# Exploding screen

Tags: explosions

I not quite sure if that's the right place to ask. Feel free to suggest a better place.

So the phone of a friend suddenly "exploded" causing the following:

[image: ruptured screen]

I've just seen the picture.

This happened under room temperatures.
Since I couldn't see the phone and I'm not very sure what could cause that (except the battery) I thought I'd ask you..

She told me the battery looks alright, so what else could have caused that?

PS: feel free to add better tags

Comment: Shattered, not exploded.  And you can see an impact point at the lower right. It probably banged into something - like a door knob while in a pocket.  The "bang" may have happened earlier, and the shattering took place later in order to relieve the stresses in the glass.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because physics doesn't care about how people are destroying their phones and it can't be used to remotely debug a "crime scene". Science requires access to the evidence.

Comment: The screen was absolutely alright and the phone lied still on a table without anyone touching it. This happened without any external influence.

Comment: A friend of mine once brought home a pretty looking glob of glass that she found in a bin outside the door of a glass-blowing studio.  She sat it on her bookshelf where, several weeks later, it woke her up by suddenly exploding in the middle of the night.  That is just another example of what @PeterDiehr meant when he said, "...shattering took place later in order to relieve stresses in the glass."  The "glass" in cell-phone screens is not just ordinary window-glass:  It is a high-tech, highly tempered material.

Comment: Then the damage had occurred previously, or the frame had been twisted - which leads to stress in the glass.  Heat-treated glass that has not been properly annealed can shatter spontaneously; that's why the glass blower puts the work back into the flame after each step, to allow the glass to relax.

Answer (score 1):

Solids are essentially incompressible, so if the glass or perspex was under abnormally high tension, then the material would be forced to shatter.

This could be down to bad manufacturing, or if the phone's structure/shape was damaged at a previous point in time (solids can be compressed to a minimal degree so this may have happened some time ago). Looking at the total shattering of the screen I think this is more than possible.